# AFNetworking freeze my GUI

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, afnetworking-2

if load view, i need load my UItableView with afnetworking, but GUI freeze

after complete download - gui unfreeze

my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (![self isExistsClub]) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            [self loadDataToFile];
        });



        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadClubsData:) name:@"loadClubsData" object:nil];
    }
}

- (void)loadClubsData:(NSNotification *)not {

    if ([[not object] boolValue]) {

        [_clubsTableView reloadData];

    }   
}

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"somesite/api/clubs.json"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id clubsData) {

    /* some code parse JSON */

    NSNumber *clubLoad = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loadClubsData" object:clubLoad];


}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: where do you post the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i remake parse class and it's work correct